# Create tabular view from the json data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to create a tabular view from the below json data.

```
{"data_report":[{"data":[1,2,0,3],"label":"Test1","backgroundColor":"blue"},
            {"data":[3,4,2,5],"label":"test2","backgroundColor":"#a3eaae"},
            {"data":[2,3,1,4],"label":"test3","backgroundColor":"#37bd11"},
            {"data":[1,2,0,3],"label":"test4","backgroundColor":"#43bee3"},
            {"data":[1,2,0,3],"label":"test5","backgroundColor":"#a3eaae"},
            {"data":[0,1,0,2],"label":"test6","backgroundColor":"#1195bd"},
            {"data":[0,1,0,2],"label":"test7","backgroundColor":"#aeb5b7"},
            {"data":[1,2,0,3],"label":"test8","backgroundColor":"pink"}] ,
  "weeks":["Week 1 ","Week 2 ","Week 3 ","Week 4 "]
}
```

From the above json I have to create table as
[image]

IS it possible to parse the data as form as table using json.stringfy

Comment: Of course possible, you can iterate through records and add to table rows

Comment: can you give some example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const input = {
  "data_report": [{
      "data": [1, 2, 0, 3],
      "label": "Test1",
      "backgroundColor": "blue"
    },
    {
      "data": [3, 4, 2, 5],
      "label": "test2",
      "backgroundColor": "#a3eaae"
    },
    {
      "data": [2, 3, 1, 4],
      "label": "test3",
      "backgroundColor": "#37bd11"
    },
    {
      "data": [1, 2, 0, 3],
      "label": "test4",
      "backgroundColor": "#43bee3"
    },
    {
      "data": [1, 2, 0, 3],
      "label": "test5",
      "backgroundColor": "#a3eaae"
    },
    {
      "data": [0, 1, 0, 2],
      "label": "test6",
      "backgroundColor": "#1195bd"
    },
    {
      "data": [0, 1, 0, 2],
      "label": "test7",
      "backgroundColor": "#aeb5b7"
    },
    {
      "data": [1, 2, 0, 3],
      "label": "test8",
      "backgroundColor": "pink"
    }
  ],
  "weeks": ["Week 1 ", "Week 2 ", "Week 3 ", "Week 4 "]
}

let thString = input.weeks.reduce((res, h) => res + '<th>' + h + '</th>', "<th></th>");

$('#thead').html(thString);
let sum = [0, 0, 0, 0];
input.data_report.forEach(tr => {
  let trString = "<td>" + tr.label + "</td>"; tr.data.forEach((val, index) => { 
  trString += '<td>' + val + '</td>';
  sum[index] += val;
  })
  $('#tbody').append("<tr>" + trString + "</tr>");
});
const resultRow = sum.reduce((res, val) => res + '<td class="text-bold">'+val+'</td>', '<td>Total</td>')
$('#tbody').append(resultRow);
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0 4px;
  text-align: right;
}
.text-bold {
  font-weight: 600;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead id="thead"></thead>
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the sum of week 1 ,week2 ,week3,week 4 below the table

Comment: To get sum, you'll have to use `forEach` instead `reduce`. Do addition as well as string building with <td> while iterating

Comment: Is it required to change the input.data_report.forEach(tr => {
  const trString = "<td>" + tr.label + "</td>" + tr.data.reduce((res, d) => res + '<td>' + d + '</td>', "");
  $('#tbody').append("<tr>" + trString + "</tr>");
});

Comment: Any clue to get the sum of the data

Comment: Update to display sum

Comment: Is it possible to display on click the first cell will console week1, value:1,Test1 on second row 3rd column click  week2, value:2,Test1